Necessary and sufficient condition(s) for differentiability of product of two functions
f(x) is a continuous and differentiable function at x=a such that f(a)≠0.
g(x) is an arbitrary function such that the product function f(x)×g(x) is continuous and differentiable at x=a.
Find necessary and sufficient condition(s) to be imposed on f and g for such a situation to be possible (If such a situation is possible at all).
Most books say (which is true) that:

If f(x) is continuous and differentiable at x=a, and g(x) is not differentiable at x=a, then if f(a)=0, the product function becomes differentiable at x=a.

But, my question is (as I've already written above): are there more such possibilities of differentiability of the product function? (Examples/general conditions both acceptable)

If $f(a)\neq 0,$ then $f(x)\neq 0$ in some interval around $a.$ Assume $fg$ is differentiable at $a.$ Then $g=(fg)/f$ is differentiable at $a.$

Yeah but i need a concrete example/absolutely general conditions
